# trying to send a value through a get request, get the value but it doesn't send html page in response

Tags: javascript, ajax, sequelize.js

What I am trying to do is get the value typed into the #pinCode input and send it in my ajax request to my server side so I can use that value as a search parameter in my sequelize query.

Right now I can access the value with req.query.loginID and I can use it to run a query but when I try to send a html page back in response it just stays on the same page. and doesn't do anything

This is the GET request on the browser side js.

```
$('#pinCode').keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode === 13) {
            const pin = {
                loginID: $('#pinCode').val().trim()
            }

            function loginwithID(p) {
                $.get('/home', p, function() {
                    $('#pinCode').val('')
                })
            }

            loginwithID(pin);
        }
 });
```

This is the GET request on server side and also my sequelize query.

```
    app.get("/home", function (req, res) {
        db.Employee.findAll(
            {
                where: {
                    loginID: req.query.loginID
                }
            }).then(function (data) {
                res.send(homePage.render(memberPage.render(data)));
            })
    });
```

I read that you can make a POST request for this as well but I don't know how I would make this into a POST so if that is somehow easier open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the response to your HTML.

```
$.get('/home', p, function(data) {
    $('#pinCode').append(data);
});
```

Comment: doing that gives me an internal server error 500 I am trying to get the value typed into the #pinCode input and send it to my server side so I can do a sequelize query with that pin code

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood you. You can have the pin as part of the URL. Otherwise you should make a POST, with a payload